# Mysql выборка постов за последние 7 активных дней

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать выборку из бд за последние 7 активных дней

есть таблица post и в ней есть

## id | date

99 | 2018-02-25 05:23:16
98 | 2018-02-25 05:04:16
97 | 2018-02-22 07:08:16
96 | 2018-02-20 05:02:16
95 | 2018-02-19 03:18:36
94 | 2018-01-20 01:08:16
93 | 2018-01-19 05:23:16
92 | 2018-01-15 05:13:16
91 | 2018-01-13 03:23:16
80 | 2018-01-10 05:25:16

Как из этого видно записей за один день может быть несколько а патом несколько дней не быть

И нужно получить данные за последние активные 7 дней

Результат:

## id | date

99 | 2018-02-25 05:23:16
98 | 2018-02-25 05:04:16
97 | 2018-02-22 07:08:16
96 | 2018-02-20 05:02:16
95 | 2018-02-19 03:18:36
94 | 2018-01-20 01:08:16
93 | 2018-01-19 05:23:16
92 | 2018-01-15 05:13:16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
  from post
 where date>=(
    select min(dt) from (
        select distinct date(date) dt
          from post
         order by 1 desc
         limit 7
      ) x
 )
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f33f1/4)

Comment: Спс, то что надо